# Too deeply nested error with beamer

Tags: beamer, errors, lists, itemize

in this code I get a `too deeply nested error`

I used this command `\usepackage[loadonly]{enumitem}`  to fix error,but all items become on the same level. Any help please?

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
 \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
 \usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup{font=small}
 \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{animate}
  \usepackage{movie 15}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
 \xyoption{arc}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
 %\usepackage{multimedia}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 

 \begin{document}
 \section{section1 }
 \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Optimisation problem
 \begin{itemize}
 \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=green}
 \item \tiny chamfer distance
 \item Algorithme d’optimisation
 \textit{\begin{enumerate}
 \item step1
 \item step2
 \item step3
 \begin{itemize}
 \item step3.1
 \item step3.2
 \item step3.3
 \item step3.4
 \itemstep3.5
 \end{itemize}
 \item step4
 \end{enumerate} }
 \end{itemize}
 \end{itemize}
 }
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `enumitem` with `beamer`, it's not really compatible with it.  And you should almost never need the `loadonly` option of `enumitem` unless you really know what you are doing. There's also a typo in your code: `\usepackage{movie 15}` (typical Mac auto correct problem).  Is that in the code you tried to run?

Comment: @AlanMunn, thanks, surely, there is a solution. I will find  it.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

The error message `too deeply nested error` is removed if the `description` environment is used. It seems that (and I quote) `"There are three predefined environments for creating lists, namely enumerate, itemize, and description. The
first two can be nested to depth three"`. This comment pushes me to use 'description' and it does work. Please check page 111-114 of beamer user manual.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
\usepackage{etex}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
 \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
 \usepackage{caption}
 \captionsetup{font=small}
 \captionsetup{labelformat=empty}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{animate}
 \usepackage{movie 15}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{epsfig}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
% \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
% \xyoption{arc}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
 %\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow} 

 \begin{document}
 \section{section1}
\begin{frame}[shrink=0]
\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
 \begin{enumerate}
 \item Optimisation problem
 \begin{itemize}
 \setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=green}
 \item{\tiny chamfer distance}
 \item Algorithme d'optimisation
\textit{\begin{itemize}
 \item step1
 \item step2
 \item step3
 \begin{description}[abc]  % for indentation of length of abc
 \item[$\bullet$] step3.1
 \item[$\bullet$] step3.2
 \item[$\bullet$] step3.3
 \item[$\bullet$] step3.4
 \item[$\bullet$] step3.5
 \end{description}
 \item step4 
 \end{itemize}}
 \end{itemize}
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, soory it does not work for me. I have an overflow arithmetic error.

Comment: Hi, just to make sure, I recompiled your OP codes without any overflow arithmetic errors on my end (Window, TeXworks). There is an `inputenc` package for XeLaTeX. If you use PdfLaTeX, please comment it out. Just for your information.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the problem. I make an error when I get an overflow arithmetic. I finish my presentation and november 21 I will show it. Good luck for me!